# React Hot Module Reload refresh when nothing updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-refresh

I'm using https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin and it works good with react components. But sometimes I update a code that is not about a component directly and then I only see a message `[HMR] Nothing hot updated` in a console. To use the code I have to reload a page. Is it possible to configure the tool to refresh page automaticaly when "Nothing hot updated" ?
Thanks.